# Ebean: Setting a List<String> for setParameter() in RawSql

Tags: java, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.2

In a Play application (2.2.x) I'm using RawSql to fetch Objects and I get the following Exception:

```
Execution exception[[PersistenceException: No ScalarType registered for class java.util.ArrayList]]
```

My model basically looks like

```
@Entity()
public class Metadata extends Model {
    public static Model.Finder<String, Metadata> find = new Model.Finder<String, Metadata>(String.class, Metadata.class);

    @Id
    public String recordID;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    public List<Keyword> keywords = new ArrayList<Keyword>();
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Keyword extends Model {
    @Id
    public String keyword;

    public static Model.Finder<String, Keyword> find = new Model.Finder<String, Keyword>(String.class, Keyword.class);

}
```

and a little helper bean

```
@Entity()
@Sql()
public class RecordId extends Model {
    @Id
    public String recordId;
}
```

Now I want to find all Records that have a List of Keywords. So I wrote a RawSql that lookes like this

```
SELECT metadata_record_id as recordId
FROM metadata_keyword
WHERE keyword_keyword IN (?)
GROUP BY recordId
HAVING count(recordId) = ?
ORDER BY recordId
```

In my Controller I use setParameter to fill the Parameters.

```
RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder.parse(sql).create();
List<RecordId> query = Ebean.find(RecordId.class).setRawSql(rawSql)
                .setParameter(1, stringList)
                .setParameter(2, stringList.size())
                .findList();
```

What am I missing here? Converting the string list into a comma separated string is not working, what I was expecting. I could just concatenate the query string and not use setParameter(), but I guess that would be prone (at least in theory) to sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty much old and you would have moved on but,
it's this line

> WHERE keyword_keyword IN (?)

Remove the ( ) on the sides. 
That should do it.

And it's better to name them than using things that way.

Comment: Thank you. Even late answers might help others, so no worries. But if I remember correctly, I tried that and it did not work. But my memory might be wrong.

Comment: sad to hear that, I'll retest it at some point and update this then.